# How to support all devices orientations within Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, dynamic, storyboard

I am working with implementing a "device-agnostic" design within Xcode Storyboards.  Working with containerviews is working well (although the cells are not getting re-sized messages properly when the orientation changes).

However, I have the following layout which I am trying to support as much through the Storyboard as possible.  I am considering separate view controllers for each of the display sizes/orientations, but was hoping to see if there was a better solution:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple provide new features size classes in x code 6.Use size classes and auto layout which help you to support all the orientationa and all the devices.
These are some tutorial.which may help you.

http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2014/08/working-with-size-classes-in-interface-builder/

http://carpeaqua.com/2014/06/14/thinking-in-terms-of-ios-8-size-classes/